# Unable to drag and drop control xamarin.forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have visual studio 2017 with the last version of xamarin.  Now I can't drag and drop any control from tool box to design page in xamarin project

Comment: I've been doing forms for well over a year now and I'm either missing something or not but my experience is that you can't and never could design your UI for forms in a visual designer, it's all done through writing the XAML yourself.

Comment: But I think there are some thing wrong. Nothing appear in properties tab if I click on any control also

Comment: Yeah, it’s not what you think. Enhancements to VS 2019 though may assist with all of that ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview#forms-property-panel

Comment: Thanks . But what about properties tab . Nothing appear on it.  So I can't edit any properties for any control.  There are something missing in android SDK ??

Comment: did you read the link? VS 2019 looks to have that functionality. What version are you on?

Comment: Visual studio 2017

Comment: there’s your answer. It’s coming in 2019 version